# You cannot call isValid() on a form that is not bound - Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I trying to create a form with Symfony but I recieve an error:

> You cannot call isValid() on a form that is not bound.

1. I have class User that with annotations and Doctrine are saved in DB. Class User has getters and setters generated with Doctrine.
2. I have UserTye.php:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Iftodi\DesignBundle\Form;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

   class UserType extends AbstractType
   {

       public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
       {
           $builder->add('name');
           $builder->add('username');
           $builder->add('email','email');
           $builder->add('password','password');

       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return "userRegister";
       }
   }

   ?>
   ```
3. In Controller:

   ```
   function registerAction()
   {
       $user = new User();
       $form = $this->createForm(new UserRegister(),$user);

       $request = $this->getRequest();

       if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
           $form->bindRequest ($request);

       if($form->isValid())
       {

       }

       return $this->render("IftodiDesignBundle:User:register.html.twig", 
               array('form' => $form->createView())
               );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

You only bind your form if you have a post request, but always call isValid on it. As the message says: if it's not bound, you cannot. Reorganize your code like this:

```
if ("POST" === $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maelyn's answer is correct.

Here's an updated snippet of the code: for Symfony 2.1+

```
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do something with $form
    }
}
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1#no-more-bindrequest

If you are not in a controller but in a twig extension, you can pass the request stack through your service injection declaration in services.yml in your bundle (note Symfony 2.4 version).

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request

```
services:
  your_service_name:
     class: YourBundle\YourTwigExtension
     arguments: [@request_stack]
```

Then in your extension

```
namespace YourBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class YourTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
   private $request;

   public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack)
   {
       $tmp_request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
       if ($tmp_request) 
       {
          $this->request = $tmp_request;
       }
   }

   // add your filter/function/extension name declarations ...       

   public function yourFancyMethod()
   {
        if($this->request)
        {
             if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod()) 
             {
                  $form->bind($this->request);

                  if ($form->isValid()) 
                  {
                      // do something with $form
                  }
             }
        }
   }

}
```